# Como deixar Activity em tela cheia?

Tags: android, android-activity

Tenho a seguinte activity:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de remover as barras que estão destacadas pelo retângulo amarelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei alterar AndroidManifest.xml adicionando a seguinte linha, mas a aplicação para de funcionar:

```
android:theme=”@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Segue meu AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xxx" >  
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>    
</manifest>
```

Minha classe construtora:

```
package xxx;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //getSupportActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

/*    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }*/
}
```

- API mínima: 16
- API máxima: 23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Site do developer android tem uma documentação sobre isso. porém segue o trecho de código para você ocultar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Esconde tanto a barra de navegação e a barra de status .
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
              | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

e segue o link para estudo [Hiding the Navigation Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)